# How to insert web page (html) to a database using Symfony?

Tags: php, html, mysql, symfony

We have two different servers. On one we have CMS and on the other we have frontend. Frontend server is based on Symfony.

We need to built up a caching mechanism/database insertion into the frontend server.

So far I have built up a MySql tables called static_content using doctrine.

[image]

And this is the structure inside the Static Content.

[image]

This is the current code which I have

```
    public function parseAction() {
    $staticContent = new StaticContent();
    $staticContent->setData('html');

    $doctrine = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $doctrine->persist($staticContent);
    $doctrine->flush();

    return new Response($staticContent);
}

public function showExistationalAction($staticContentId) {
    $staticContent = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(StaticContent::class)
        ->find($staticContentId);

    if(!$staticContent) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException(
            'No html has been found'. $staticContentId
        );
    }
    return new Response($staticContent->getData());
}
```

We are using Symfony 2.8 with MySql 5.7.

So my exact problem is how can I insert the whole web page to Data field in the StaticContent Entity ? Is there a variable which just saves the HTML content in Symfony ? What do I invoke instead of setData('html'); ? 
Actually I believe that I need guidance.

Comment: And how are you going to invalid the cache of a webpage if the user changes the webpage within the CMS?

Comment: Hey Thanks Raymond. 
That's other problem which I am going to solve. One at the time.

Comment: Why don't you use a cache system like varnish for example ? :)

Comment: Hey Mcsky, because those are the requirements that I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this;

```
$this->get('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager')->persist($staticContent);
$this->get('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager')->flush();
```

Comment: Thanks Mert, for the quick answer. 
But isn't just this what I am trying ? Could you tell me the difference between this what you have written and 
 $doctrine = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $doctrine->persist($staticContent);
    $doctrine->flush();

Answer (score 0):

You can use the symfony bundle for full page cache. The cache is available for zeroing based on the modification date of the content. https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/cache.html

Comment: Hmm, nice solution. But with this I don't insert anything to the database and if I read it correctly I have to put when it expires and I don't want for it ever to expire.